# Free Spin Wheel refreshes in 28 days?

Tags: bloons-td-battles

In Bloons TD Battles, when you go to Quick Play, there is a little wheel you can spin every  couple of hours. (i think its 8).  When I spun it recently it says '28d 5hr' remaining... what? How?

Comment: Why do you think the refresh rate is 8 hours? Does it say that?

Comment: Because it has always been 8hr for me but im unsure coz this is the one exception  and there could be more